# ActiveRecord::Relation cannot use named association in where clause of join

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, associations, join, relation

How do I use a named association in the where clause associated with a join?

```
class Pet < ActiveRecord::Base
    belongs_to :owner
end

class Owner < ActiveRecord::Base
    has_many :dogs, :class_name => 'Pet', :foreign_key =>  :owner_id
end


Owner.joins(:dogs).where(:dogs => {:name => 'fido'}).to_sql
```

generates:

```
"SELECT `owners`.* FROM  `owners`  INNER JOIN `pets` ON `pets`.`owner_id` = `owners`.`id` WHERE  (`dogs`.`name` = 'fido')"
```

Note that the `WHERE` clause is looking in the `dogs` table instead of the `pets` table

For reference:

http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_querying.html#specifying-conditions-on-the-joined-tables

Answer (score 1):

It appears this is the expected behavior - you need to specify the table name in the hash, not the association name.  This is a little unfortunate because I think it'd be useful construct queries based more on their model definition and less on schema they sit in front of.