# Activerecord where condition with join without table name prefix

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, activerecord

I have 2 tables. I use table prefix x_.

1. User (table x_users)
2. Comment (table x_comments)

I want to find out total count after inner join.

This query works fine.

```
User.joins(:comments).where(x_comments: {something: 1}).count
```

How can I remove x_ from where condition to make this call generic?

**Models**

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
    has_many :comments, dependent: :destroy
end

class Comment < ActiveRecord::Base
    attr_accessible :something
    belongs_to :user
end
```

Comment: Is `User.joins(:follows).where(follows: {something: 1}).count` not working? Your users' association is with `follows`, so it should work.

Comment: Post your models too

Comment: You can use `Comment.table_name =>` instead.

Comment: @RAJ : Updated models and added class definitions.

Comment: @BroiSatse : That works. Is it a proper rails way or work around? Thanks.

Comment: Similar questions: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36546960/joins-and-where-request-on-association-with-custom-table-name,
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4103677/activerecordrelation-cannot-use-named-association-in-where-clause-of-join,
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45947285/rails-using-join-with-custom-named-associations. Unfortunately none explains why this is like this.

Answer (score 1):

As  @BroiSatse already mentioned, You can use [`ActiveRecord::Base.table_name`](http://apidock.com/rails/ActiveRecord/ModelSchema/ClassMethods/table_name) to set the table name explicitly in a model and to get the table name in a query for genericity.

You query would be:

```
User.joins(:comments).where(Comment.table_name: {something: 1}).count
```

Setting a table name explicitly:

```
class Comment < ActiveRecord::Base
  self.table_name = "x_comments"
end
```

You can override the `table_name` method like this:

```
class Comment < ActiveRecord::Base
  def self.table_name
    "x_" + super
  end
end
Comment.table_name # => "x_comments"
```

Answer (score 0):

Consider writing your conditions as scopes and let ActiveRecord handle the table aliasing for you.

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :comments, dependent: :destroy

  def self.for_comment_something(foo)
    joins(:comments).
    merge(Comment.for_something(foo))
  end
end

class Comment < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :something
  belongs_to :user

  def self.for_something(foo)
    where(something: foo)
  end 
end
```

Documentation for ActiveRecord::Relation#merge is [here](http://apidock.com/rails/ActiveRecord/SpawnMethods/merge).

Put it all together like

```
User.for_comments_something(1).count
```