# joins() and where() request on association with custom table name

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

I have two models

**Album.rb**

```
class Album < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :tracks
  self.table_name = 'prefix_album'
end
```

**Track.rb**

```
class Track < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :album
  self.table_name = 'prefix_track'
end
```

Now, because reasons, the table names are prefixed, so I have `prefix_album` and `prefix_track` tables in my database. For basic use, it works fine.

Now the problem with the following query :

```
Album.joins(:tracks).where(tracks: { id: [10, 15] })
```

Results in the following SQL :

```
SELECT * FROM "prefix_albums" INNER JOIN "prefix_tracks" ON "prefix_tracks"."album_id" = "prefix_albums"."id" WHERE "tracks"."id" IN (10, 15)
```

Which fails because `WHERE "tracks"."id"` should be `WHERE "prefix_tracks"."id"`. Any idea why active_record is able to get the correct table name for `.joins(:tracks)` but not for `.where(tracks: {})` ?

Anyway I have figured this workout : `Album.joins(:tracks).merge(Track.where(id: [10,15]))` which gives the same result and works.

But I would like to know why the former didn't work

Comment: Try `Album.joins(:tracks).where(prefix_tracks: { id: [10, 15] })`

Answer (score 2):

Try it like :

```
Album.joins(:tracks).where(prefix_tracks: { id: [10, 15] })
```

You can add `table_name` to the model like :

```
class Album < ActiveRecord::Base
  self.table_name = "prefix_album"
end
```

Comment: Yes it works but that's just another workaround, and an unstable one (if you change the setting of the table name it will break)

Comment: then add `table_name` to the model and it will work from one place.