# Rails - Using join with custom-named associations

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, postgresql, activerecord, ruby-on-rails-5

I have the following model

```
class Measurement < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :examination, class_name: "TestStructure", foreign_key: "examination_id"

end
```

The association is actually made to the TestStructure model, but the association name is examination. **There is no examination table.**

The problem arises when I'm querying using `join`. The following query

```
Measurement.joins(:examination).where(examination: { year: 2016, month: 5 })
```

fails, with this error

```
ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid:
   PG::UndefinedTable: ERROR:  missing FROM-clause entry for table "examination"
   LINE 1: ...d" = "measurements"."examination_id" WHERE "examinati...
# --- Caused by: ---
 # PG::UndefinedTable:
 #   ERROR:  missing FROM-clause entry for table "examination"
 #   LINE 1: ...d" = "measurements"."examination_id" WHERE "examinati...
```

So clearly, the `examinations` table doesn't exists, but I can't find a way to tell ActiveRecord I'm using a named association instead of the default one.

Any insights?

Comment: With `includes`, `joins` and `references` you need to use the relation name as defined in your model. With `where` you need to use the exact table name. So if your model `TestStructure` store data in the table `custom_named_table`, you need to do `Measurement.joins(:examination).where(custom_named_table: { year: 2016, month: 5 })` (you can find the table name using `TestStructure.table_name`) (see my previous answers on that subject: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24266069/join-multiple-tables-with-active-records/24266583#24266583)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

`where` expects the actual table name, it just inserts it in SQL:

```
Article.where(whatever: {you: 'want'}).to_sql
=> "SELECT `articles`.* FROM `articles` WHERE `whatever`.`you` = 'want'"
```

So you may use:

```
Measurement.joins(:examination).where(test_structures: { year: 2016, month: 5 })
```

**But it's not good**

Then you depend on table name while Model should abstract such things. You could use [`merge`](https://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/SpawnMethods.html#method-i-merge):

```
Measurement.joins(:examination).merge(TestStructure.where(year: 2016, month: 5))
```

Comment: you are correct. Let me try your method, hopefully it won't perform more than one query, and I'll get back to you.

Comment: I will call out that using `.merge()` along with `.joins()` has been a huge lifesaver for me on the Rails project I work on for a living. We have Rails Engines, so each of the DB table names for our ActiveRecord models have the engine name as a prefix. This causes complexity with using an association's name in a `where()` call, I would have to use the DB table's name as a Hash key instead.  The combination of `.joins()` and `merge()` has made ActiveRecord querying a much more pleasurable experience for this project.

Answer (score 5):

For joins you use the association name, but for where you need to use the table name

```
Measurement.joins(:examination).where(test_structures: { year: 2016, month: 5 })
```

or

```
Measurement.joins(:examination).where('test_structures.year': 2016, 'test_structures.month': 5 )
```

Answer (score 1):

In this example table name `examinations` should be provided instead of an association name `examination` in the `where` method.

```
Measurement.jons(:examination).where(examinations: { year: 2016, month: 5 })
```

Comment: Please correct me if I'm wrong, does eager_load actually retrieves records into memory? I'm aiming to not do that, thus the join.

Comment: @Sebastialonso: according to the activerecord docs I am wrong and you can use `joins`, but the table name caveat is crucial.

Answer (score 0):

In somecase you need to add `.references(associations)`

```
Measurement.joins(:examination).merge(TestStructure.where(year: 2016, month: 5)).references(:examination)
```